# How can I loop through different values in a function?

Tags: python

I have a function `SWRC()` that returns the outputs: `optimized_SR`, `yrly_withd_ar`, `est_retirement_bal`. I want to loop through values of a variable inside the function and check it the value of a 2nd variable against a value. ex:

The variable `a = SWRC(yrly_withd_ar)[1]` returns a number between 1 and 0.

```
yrly_withd_ar = 0

a = SWRC(yrly_withd_ar)[1]

while True:
    if a < .5:
        print(SWRC(yrly_withd_ar))
        continue
    else:
        return SWRC()
    yrly_withd_ar += 1000
```

the function SWRC() is below. (Im new to python so Im sure it could be cleaned up).

```
def SWRC():  
    ## makes a list of years that are in pre-retirement. will need this to calculate returns
    pre_ret_range = []

    for pre_yr in range(0, yrs_left):
        pre_ret_range.append(current_yr + pre_yr)
    
    
    ## makes a list of years that are in post-retirement. will need this to calculate returns
    
    post_ret_range = []

    for post_yr in range(0, retirement_yrs ):
        post_ret_range.append(retire_yr + post_yr)
    
    total_range = pre_ret_range + post_ret_range
    
    ### Glidepaths read into python
    ### first variable is the GP until retirement
    ### second variable ex vcon_AR is very conservative glide path after retirement
    GPs_file = pd.ExcelFile('A:\Sustainable Withdrawal\Python_Enhancement\Dynamic_GPs.xls')

    vcon = pd.read_excel(GPs_file, 'Very_Conservative', usecols=['Years until distributions begin', 'Stock_Alloc', 'Bond_Alloc', 'Cash_Alloc'])
    vcon_ar = pd.read_excel(GPs_file, 'Very_Conservative', usecols=['Time_Until_Death', 'Stk_Alloc', 'Bnd_Alloc', 'Csh_Alloc']).dropna()

    con = pd.read_excel(GPs_file, 'Conservative', usecols=['Years until distributions begin', 'Stock_Alloc', 'Bond_Alloc', 'Cash_Alloc'])
    con_ar = pd.read_excel(GPs_file, 'Conservative', usecols=['Time_Until_Death', 'Stk_Alloc', 'Bnd_Alloc', 'Csh_Alloc']).dropna()

    mod = pd.read_excel(GPs_file, 'Moderate', usecols=['Years until distributions begin', 'Stock_Alloc', 'Bond_Alloc', 'Cash_Alloc'])
    mod_ar = pd.read_excel(GPs_file, 'Moderate', usecols=['Time_Until_Death', 'Stk_Alloc', 'Bnd_Alloc', 'Csh_Alloc']).dropna()

    agg = pd.read_excel(GPs_file, 'Aggressive', usecols=['Years until distributions begin', 'Stock_Alloc', 'Bond_Alloc', 'Cash_Alloc'])
    agg_ar = pd.read_excel(GPs_file, 'Aggressive', usecols=['Time_Until_Death', 'Stk_Alloc', 'Bnd_Alloc', 'Csh_Alloc']).dropna()

    vagg = pd.read_excel(GPs_file, 'Very_Aggressive', usecols=['Years until distributions begin', 'Stock_Alloc', 'Bond_Alloc', 'Cash_Alloc'])
    vagg_ar = pd.read_excel(GPs_file, 'Very_Aggressive', usecols=['Time_Until_Death', 'Stk_Alloc', 'Bnd_Alloc', 'Csh_Alloc']).dropna()
    
    ## these variables are used if client selects a custom portfolio

    custom = vcon
    custom['Stock_Alloc'] = custom_s
    custom['Bond_Alloc'] = custom_b
    custom['Cash_Alloc'] = custom_c

    ## in case I need to add in later

    custom_ar = vcon_ar
    custom_ar['Stk_Alloc'] = custom_s
    custom_ar['Bnd_Alloc'] = custom_b
    custom_ar['Csh_Alloc'] = custom_c
    
    ### If statements setting portfolio equal to the dataframe that corresponds to the client risk tolerance
    portfolio = ''
    portfolio_ar = ''

    if risk_tol == 'vcon':
        portfolio = vcon
        portfolio_ar = vcon_ar
    
    elif risk_tol == 'con':
        portfolio = con
        portfolio_ar = con_ar

    elif risk_tol == 'mod':
        portfolio = mod
        portfolio_ar = mod_ar

    elif risk_tol == 'agg':
        portfolio = agg
        portfolio_ar = agg_ar

    elif risk_tol == 'vagg':
        portfolio = vagg
        portfolio_ar = vagg_ar

    elif risk_tol == 'custom':
        portfolio = custom
        portfolio_ar = custom_ar
    
    else:
        print('Error with portfolio selection')
    
    # Calculating Porfolio return for glidepath pre retirment.
    port_yrs = portfolio[portfolio['Years until distributions begin'] < yrs_left] 
    returns_pre = []

    for i in range(0, yrs_left):
    
        stk_percent = port_yrs['Stock_Alloc'].iloc[i]
        bnd_percent = port_yrs['Bond_Alloc'].iloc[i]
        csh_percent = port_yrs['Cash_Alloc'].iloc[i]
        stk_returns = stock_returns[pre_ret_range].iloc[:, i]
        bnd_returns = bond_returns[pre_ret_range].iloc[:, i]
        csh_returns = cash_returns[pre_ret_range].iloc[:, i]
        inflation_exp = inflation[pre_ret_range].iloc[:,i]
    
        returns_pre.append(
            ((stk_percent * stk_returns + bnd_percent * bnd_returns + csh_returns * csh_returns)/(1 + (inf_returns*inflation_exp)))
       
            )   

    pre_ret_returns = pd.DataFrame.from_records(np.transpose(returns_pre), columns = pre_ret_range)
    
    # Calculating Porfolio return for glidepath post retirment.
    port_yrs_ar = portfolio_ar[portfolio_ar['Time_Until_Death'] < retirement_yrs-1]
    
    returns_post = []

    for i in range(0, retirement_yrs):
    
        stk_percent_ar = port_yrs_ar['Stk_Alloc'].iloc[i]
        bnd_percent_ar = port_yrs_ar['Bnd_Alloc'].iloc[i]
        csh_percent_ar = port_yrs_ar['Csh_Alloc'].iloc[i]
        stk_returns_ar = stock_returns[post_ret_range].iloc[:, i]
        bnd_returns_ar = bond_returns[post_ret_range].iloc[:, i]
        csh_returns_ar = cash_returns[post_ret_range].iloc[:, i]
        inflation_exp = inflation[post_ret_range].iloc[:,i]
    
        returns_post.append(
            ((stk_percent_ar * stk_returns_ar + bnd_percent_ar * bnd_returns_ar + csh_returns_ar * csh_returns_ar)/(1 + (inf_returns*inflation_exp)))
        )
        
    post_ret_returns = pd.DataFrame.from_records(np.transpose(returns_post), columns = post_ret_range)
    
    # joining returns together.
    all_returns = pre_ret_returns.join(post_ret_returns, how='outer') 
    AR = all_returns[current_yr] * year_fraction_left
    column1 = pd.DataFrame(AR)

    all_returns[current_yr] = column1 = pd.DataFrame(AR)
    
    ### calculates year 1 balances. needed because need to incorporate the starting balance. Appends to the list.
    scenarios_bal = []

    yr1_bal = np.maximum(0,1 + all_returns.iloc[:,0]) * start_bal + yrly_con
    scenarios_bal.append(
        (round(yr1_bal, 2))
        )
    
    ### calcs all years after 1 and appends to the list. 
    for i in range(1,len(total_range)):
        cuminf_exp = cuminflation[total_range].iloc[:,i]
        cuminf_con = 1 if inf_contributions == 0 else cuminf_exp
        cuminf_with = 1 if inf_withdrawals == 0 else cuminf_exp
    
        contribution = yrly_con if i <= yrs_left else 0
        withdrawal = -1 * yrly_withd_ar if i > yrs_left else 0
    
        prev_balance = scenarios_bal[i - 1]
    
        new_bal = (1 + all_returns.iloc[:, i]) * prev_balance + (contribution*cuminf_con)+ (withdrawal*cuminf_with)
        new_balance = np.maximum(round(new_bal,2), 0)
    
        scenarios_bal.append(new_balance) 
    
    #dataframe of all scenario balances.
    scenarios_balances = pd.DataFrame.from_records(np.transpose(scenarios_bal), columns = total_range)
    
    # calculates the success rates.
    fails_per_yr = []
    percentages = []
    yr__ = []


    for i in range(0, len(total_range)):
        fails_per_yr.append((scenarios_balances[current_yr + i] == 0).sum())
        percent = 1 - fails_per_yr[i]/10000
        percentages.append(percent)
        yr__.append(current_yr + i)
    
    succ_rate = pd.DataFrame(percentages)
    succ_rate.insert(0, "Year", total_range, True)
    # success_rates creates a list of % by year of a successful outcome with the current client variables.
    success_rates = succ_rate.set_axis(['Year', 'Success %'], axis=1, inplace=False)
    
    optimized_SR = success_rates['Success %'].iloc[2]

    ## est_retirement_bal is the 50th percentile balance at retirement
    est_retirement_bal = scenarios_balances[[retire_yr]].quantile(q=0.5, axis=0, interpolation='nearest').item()
    est_retirement_bal_user_percentile = scenarios_balances[[retire_yr]].quantile(q=user_percentile, axis=0, interpolation='nearest')
    
    return optimized_SR, yrly_withd_ar, est_retirement_bal
```

Comment: What parameter(s) does SWRC take? Can you show us the function itself? It's a bit unclear what you want to do.

Comment: Hi Stuart, its a pretty long function but I did include it now. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: @MikeDrum: It is worth to try to get to a minimum reproducible example. More often than not you find the issue during the shortening.

Comment: @guidot I have been able to use this function when I can manually input the variable values. The issue arises when I try to run multiple values through the function until I get a specific output.  In a way I am trying to optimize the function

Comment: @MikeDrum It's difficult to make sense of this code as `SWRC` neither takes any parameter nor alters the value of `yrly_withd_ar`. `a = SWRC(yrly_withd_ar)[1]` would cause an error and `SWRC()[1]` would simply return the value of the global variable `yrly_withd_ar`.

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to find the lowest value of `yrly_with_ar` for which `optimized_SR >= .5`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find the lowest `yrly_withd_ar` for which `optimized_SR >= .5`, then you can pass `yrly_withd_ar` as a parameter of `SWRC`. There is no need to include `yrly_withd_ar` among the return values of `SWRC`, as the function does nothing to change this variable. But you can include it in the return values of your new optimizing function, if is useful.

```
def SWRC(yrly_withd_ar):
    ...
    return optimized_SR, est_retirement_bal

def optimize_swrc(minimum_success=.5):
    yrly_withd_ar = 0
    while True:
        optimized_SR, est_retirement_bal = SWRC(yrly_withd_ar)
        if optimized_SR >= minimum_success:
             return yrly_withd_ar, optimized_SR, est_retirement_bal
        print(yrly_withd_ar, optimized_SR, est_retirement_bal)
        yrly_withd_ar += 1000
```

However, your code would benefit from restructuring - this loop will result in the same operations (e.g. reading all those Excel sheets) being unnecessarily repeated multiple times. Consider breaking `SWRC` into several shorter functions, each of which take parameters and return a result, rather than relying on global variables.

Comment: Thanks Stuart! Took your advice and organized it into functions. Found an error that was causing issues. Once that was fixed using your suggestion worked!